possible to define associated types with known relationship?
this code doesn't compile, because rustc doesn't understand that Foo::OptionOfT and Option<Foo::T> are the same thing. Is this possible to accomplish? My motivation is roughly that I'd like to be able to apply additional trait bounds that restrict the choice of T based on properties of Option<T>
#![feature(associated_type_defaults)]

trait Foo {
    type T;
    type OptionOfT = Option<Self::T>;
}

fn wrap_in_option<X: Foo>(t: X::T) -> X::OptionOfT {
    Some(t)
}

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=07a2a6751f2dbe52f4b8a4bbf149bdb6

Foo::OptionOfT and Option<Foo::T> are not the same thing. What you have is only a default. Implementations are free to specify a OptionOfT that is not Option.

well - that's part of the question. I want a fixed relationship, but of course deleting the word default also doesn't compile

Any associated type in your trait are set by the implementation; what you have is simply a default type that implementations will use if not otherwise specified. This means that OptionOfT may not be Option<T> and your wrap_in_option cannot rely on that unless further constrained:
fn wrap_in_option<X: Foo<T = T, OptionOfT = Option<T>>, T>(t: X::T) -> X::OptionOfT {
    Some(t)
}

If you want an alias for an associated type, it needs to be a separate type declaration:
trait Foo {
    type T;
}

type OptionOfT<F> = Option<<F as Foo>::T>;

fn wrap_in_option<X: Foo>(t: X::T) -> OptionOfT<X> {
    Some(t)
}


You can specify it with a qualified path.
fn wrap_in_option<X>(t: X::T) -> X::OptionOfT
where
    X: Foo<OptionOfT = Option<<X as Foo>::T>>,
{
    Some(t)
}

